# CSS box shadow is so dark when printed

Tags: printing, css

i got a div with a blur shadow on it. i am a using the CSS code below:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:  3px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);     
box-shadow:  3px 3px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
```

the problem is when the page is printed the shadow turns into dark black.
please help.

Answer (score 3):

The transparency when printing is a problem.  Your best bet is to define different styles for the printed page with a separate `print.css` stylesheet with print media query or by using a media attribute like

```
@media print {
    item {
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. currently this is what i did rather than printing a dark shadow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174583).

A work around is to apply a filter like `-webkit-filter: blur(0);` to the affected elements; this will however rasterize the element in the resulting PDF.

Comment: This makes a text inside an element unreadable (at least in Chrome 43) :(

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the printer have you tried printing anywhere else?